# How to stop inherit from Style and change the background color of textbox

Tags: wpf

Again am stuck to change the background color of my text box but the weird part is forground is works fine but not the background.

Here is my xaml

```
 <TextBox
                Name="tbHeadline" 
                Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Headline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
                Grid.Column="1"  
                Grid.Row="6" 
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                LostFocus="tbHeadline_LostFocus" 
                 />
```

in my Xaml.cs

I have the following code

```
 tbHeadline.Background = Brushes.Gray; //this not working
 tbHeadline.Foreground = Brushes.Gray; //this is working
```

here is the sample output

[image: Foreground output]
[image: Background Output]
Thanks for your help.

Update from the expert comments

Okie, i added a textbox in the grid and this what it look like

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="10" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,14,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#E6000000" />
```

Even i set the background color to Black but its not visible when i run the application.

Comment: this should be working fine. try to delete the textbox, and create new textbox and try to rebuild.

Comment: Is your error template overriding the background?

Comment: @MarkHall,that's my doubt too.

Comment: Try removing the error template reference from your xaml then see if the issue goes away, then look at your errorhandler's xaml to verify.

Comment: I tried remove the errorhandler but no luck

Comment: I just ran your code with out the errorhandler and I was able to change the background color. Try creating a simple textbox and then see it works, otherwise create a small self contained example and add it to your question that way we can use it to try to duplicate the problem

Comment: you mean ,do you remove this piece of the code Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"

Comment: Yes that is what I did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30292/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-usher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summarizing our discussion in Chat, you have a Default Style that is overriding your TextBox's Background Brush. I suggested that you set your TextBox's Default Style to Null as the answer to this [SO question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788203/how-to-override-application-styles-in-a-wpf-control-created-at-runtime).  You can do this in either the Code Behind or in the Xaml declaration of your TextBox.

```
tbHeadline.Style = null;
```

or in your Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="tbHeadline" Style="" 
         Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Headline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
         Grid.Column="1"  
         Grid.Row="6" 
         TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
         d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         LostFocus="tbHeadline_LostFocus" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet should work. You can test by creating a blank project, dropping a TextBox and setting the colors in code. Use Snoop to see if tb's background is being set in different ways or different places.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet should work. Just set style to null like this

```
<TextBox Style ={x:Null} Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="10" Grid.RowSpan="2"         Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,14,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#E6000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tbHeadline.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);`

Comment: Thanks inxs,i already tried that option like tbHeadline.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); but nothing happend

Comment: my style is overwrite it or i can say the background color is inherited from sytle.

Comment: Background needs a Object of the Type `Brush` like SolidColorBrush, GradientBrush etc. See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx